# Left Joining not returning all the records from left table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the count by doing `join` with the two tables, I am doing `group by` and `left join`.

But I am not getting all the row if that record doesn't match another table.

Here in the given query:

```
create table UserTable (
  Id integer not null,
  Name varchar(12) not null
);

insert into UserTable  values (1,  'A B');
insert into UserTable  values (2,  'A C');
insert into UserTable  values (3,  'A C A C');
insert into UserTable  values (4,  'A C C');
insert into UserTable  values (5,  'A C B');
insert into UserTable  values (6,  'A C C');
insert into UserTable  values (7,  'A C D');
insert into UserTable  values (8,  'A C E');
insert into UserTable  values (9,  'A C F');


create table LogTable (
  LogId integer not null,
  Username varchar(12) not null,
  Event varchar(12) not null
);

insert into LogTable  values (1, 'A C A C', 'Read');
insert into LogTable  values (2, 'A C F', 'Write');
insert into LogTable  values (3, 'A C F', 'Read');
insert into LogTable  values (4, 'A C C', 'Update');
insert into LogTable  values (5,'A C C', 'Read');
insert into LogTable  values (6,'A C F', 'Read');
insert into LogTable  values (7,'A C F', 'Update');
insert into LogTable  values (7,'A C F', 'Write');
insert into LogTable  values (7,'A C E','Update');
insert into LogTable  values (7,'A C F', 'Delete');
insert into LogTable  values (10,'A C B', 'Delete');
insert into LogTable  values (11, 'A C F','Copy');
insert into LogTable  values (12, 'A C B','Read');
insert into LogTable  values (13, 'A C F','Update');
insert into LogTable  values (14, 'A C F','Copy');
insert into LogTable  values (15, 'A C F','Read');
insert into LogTable  values (16, 'A C F','Update');
insert into LogTable  values (17, 'A C F','Copy');
insert into LogTable  values (18, 'A C C','Read');
insert into LogTable  values (19, 'A C D','Update');
```

I am doing:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Read,UT.Name, UT.Id 
FROM UserTable UT 
LEFT JOIN LogTable LT ON LT.Username = UT.Name 
WHERE LT.Event = 'Read'
GROUP by UT.Name, UT.Id
```

What I want is to get all the records from the `UserTable`, also if that doesn't exist in `LogTable`

If not exist make the `ReadCount` as 0.

Why is Left Joining not returning all the records from **UserTable** in this query?

Desired Output:

```
Id  |   Name    |   ReadCount
-----------------------------
1   |   A B     |   0
2   |   A C     |   0
3   |   A C A C |   1
4   |   A C C   |   2
5   |   A C B   |   1
6   |   A C C   |   2
7   |   A C D   |   0
8   |   A C E   |   0
9   |   A C F   |   3
```

Comment: Your example says Right join

Comment: What happens when you put the condition from the `WHERE`-clause in the `ON`-clause of the `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: that will work,  maybe that is I have missed?

Comment: @AkshayKriti . . . Why is the `logtable` NOT using the id?  You should be using the id rather than the name for foreign key relationships.

Comment: that table is made in such a way that it doesn't have any Id on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the condition to the `ON` clause.  However, you do not want `COUNT(*)` because you want to count the number of matches.  That would be:

```
SELECT UT.Name, UT.Id , COUNT(LT.UserName) as num_read
FROM UserTable UT LEFT JOIN
     LogTable LT
     ON LT.Username = UT.Name AND LT.Event = 'Read'
GROUP by UT.Name, UT.Id;
```

That said, this type of query is often faster with a correlated subquery:

```
select ut.*,
       (select count(*)
        from logtable lt
        where lt.username = ut.name and lt.event = 'Read'
       ) as num_read
from usertable ut;
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `logtable(username, event)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Read,UT.Name, UT.Id 
FROM UserTable UT 
LEFT JOIN LogTable LT ON LT.Username = UT.Name 
WHERE LT.Event = 'Read'
GROUP by UT.Name, UT.Id
```

you used `WHERE LT.Event = 'Read'` which makes it inner join that's why you are not getting all the rows of left table

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Read,UT.Name, UT.Id 
FROM UserTable UT 
LEFT JOIN LogTable LT ON LT.Username = UT.Name 
 and  LT.Event = 'Read'

GROUP by UT.Name, UT.Id
```

move the condition in the on clause

Comment: giving me count as `1` for missing row. but I think I need as 0